# Calling Meteor Method from within Particle Photon Stream of Promises produces error: Error("Meteor code must always run within a Fiber. "

Tags: meteor, promise

I'm connecting to Particle.io event stream and trying to call a Meteor Method with the event name and event data from the stream as arguments.

```
var Particle = Meteor.npmRequire('particle-api-js');
var particle = new Particle();

var particleLogin = particle.login({
  username: Meteor.settings.particle_username,
  password: Meteor.settings.particle_password
});

particleLogin.then(
  function(data) {
    var token = data.body.access_token;
    console.log(token);
    var eventStream = particle.getEventStream({
      deviceId: Meteor.settings.PhotonName, 
      auth: token
    });

    eventStream.then(function(stream) {
      stream.on('event', function(data) {
        console.log(data.name + ": " + data.data);
        Meteor.call('newStreamData', data.name, data.data);  //  Produces aforementioned error
      });
    });
  }
)
```

I've tried including the call from inside of a Meteor.bindEnvironment block and nothing happens.

```
stream.on('event', Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(data) {
  console.log(data.name + ": " + data.data);            //  Never gets called
  Meteor.call('newStreamData', data.name, data.data);   //  Never gets called
}));
```